# Is there any way to check read data which is read by Direct I/O (O_DIRECT) in the kernel space?

Tags: io, linux-kernel, mmap, interrupt-handling, read-write

I am using NVMe SSD and NVMe driver. My application read data from device by Direct I/O read(O_DIRECT).

I want to check (via `printk` or something) read data in the NVMe driver code (e.g., `nvme_hadle_cqe`. this is function which handle irq). **Is there any way to check data which is read by Direct I/O in the kernel space not in the user space?**

Though I am using Direct I/O, I thought nvme_handle_cqe which handle I/O interrupt will be called when Disk I/O is finished.
I learned that Read data is directly copied from Disk to user-supplied buffer when I used Direct IO. **But if so, who copy the read data to user-supplied buffer from DISK? Does this process is done by hardware? not by kernel? If so, do I not have access to this data in kernel space?**

Comment: "*who copy the read data to user-supplied buffer from DISK?*" -- Since your system has NVMe SSD. there is no "*disk*".  The storage device is connected to the system using a NVMe interface.  All commands, drive status, and data are through the NVMe interface.  The system processor can use either PIO (programmed I/O) or DMA to transfer data between memory and the NVMe controller.  When DMA is employed, the CPU (and any driver) cannot handle any data until the DMA transfer is complete.  For Direct I/O, that DMA transfer bypasses any kernel buffering.

Comment: See https://superuser.com/questions/350582/when-a-disk-read-or-disk-write-occurs-where-does-the-data-go/350592#350592

Comment: @sawdust thank u for answering. Then, there is no way to check read data (done by Direct IO) in the kernel code, right?

Comment: You would need to map user pages to kernel space using `kmap` or `kmap_atomic` to access their contents outside the context of the user process.